# Can one machine virtually host a DNS server and an Email server?

Tags: linux, centos7, zimbra

I have one question: is it manageable to host a DNS server and an Email server on one machine?

Im using proxmox as virtualization
Zimbra as the email server

Comment: **Can one machine virtually host a DNS server and an Email server?** - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Many (if not most) server roles are not mutually exclusive.

Running an authoritative name server for your own DNS domain and your email are not mutually exclusive either.

So yes, you can combine DNS with E-mail services on a single host.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer. Yes you can.

Remind, that I use also proxmox and using a DNS on the host since it reduces a lot of DNS traffic from or to the net devices.

Comment: Thanks for your assurance, does your proxmox ever crash? Or down?

Comment: Well, since i use it, nope, but remind if you wnat to use it in Production pay the License and use at least 2 nodes. Myself uses Mailcow, as it is easy to use

Comment: Thanks for your advice !

Comment: remember to accept a (my) answer if it was helpfulness